# Changing existing application to responsive angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

How do i  make an existing angular application and bootstrap was used !! How do i make it mobile responsive. Do i have to rewrite the whole css file , html files again or is there anyway. I m new to this so any help and suggestions would be really great.

Comment: You need change the .html or the css thinking "mobile first". Bootstrap css is thinking in [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), so, e.g. you write `col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-4` (if width>576px use col-7, if width>768px use col-6 and if width>992 use col-4). Possible you need change the .css to create your own media-queries.

Comment: The idea is always the same first you think the width (or the padding or the align) at minimum width, then use `@media (min-width: what-ever)`. As the "base" is bootstrap your media should be relationated with the bootstrap [break-point](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/). I know it's not the ideal in a start proyect, but if you create your own mediaqueries based in anothers break point perfhas your application lose constistencie.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

## Philosophical

Before making changes, some background on the best way to make changes will help.

### "Get" Sass & CSS

First and foremost, learn what CSS and Sass can do for you. Not necessarily to be an expert but how it can best be used.

Sass is CSS, plus features like some math and reusable variables you can define in one file for reuse (so that you only have to change your colors or other things in one place.) Like type script transpiles to JavaScript at build time, Sass/Scss files transpile to CSS at build time.

An oldie but goodie to explode your mind on what CSS means is CSS Zen Garden where Dave Shea made an HTML file and invited people to, by ONLY changing the CSS file, create a different, good looking page. See http://daveshea.com/projects/zen/ for background and some particularly good submissions. Note how, besides the pretty colors and graphics, some are better than others for different needs and aims, and remember that ALL of them use the exact same HTML. You can change your whole feel that way.

### Apply that wisdom to Angular

Once I realized how the lessons of CSS Zen Garden applied to Angular, the separation of duties between UI components and services (and finding SEPARATE layers for everything in between whether they be pipes, another layer of services, components purely for layout, etc) made so much more sense!

I'm not suggesting that you rewrite your entire application, but take the approach that if you have to change anything but your CSS then it is likely technical debt you didn't realize that you had, and attack it aggressively.

What about disabled people using screen readers? What about some weird future where it is all 3D holographic displays? Decouple your UI and not only will the code quality go up, the problem of mobile versus laptop becomes so much simpler, with the amount you have to touch becoming both small and obvious.

### Have an Agile backlog

Pretend to know there will always, always be more to do.

Step one, get it to work, no matter how awful it looks.

Step two, figure out what should be attacked within a week that can result in an improved, still-working product.

Step three, prioritize and work on them, rolling them out (not necessarily to production but at least a "user acceptance" environment) frequently.

Then repeat steps 2 and 3.

Also, "don't commit debt" might be asking too much but at least add whatever debt you introduce or see into the backlog. If your product owner doesn't want to see it, make them own it, not you.

## Technical

### PWA

*this space intentionally left blank!*

I'm not going to define "PWA" and describe the technicals of turning an Angular app into a great PWA because others are going to answer that part better than I could. Consequently, those are answers are the ones who should be awarded as THE answer, not this one.

Seriously. Upvote this if it helps you, but any answer that doesn't help you convert to a PWA isn't the "right" one.

### More, smaller, and lazy-loaded modules

This is such a minor point that I almost didn't type it. It might be best if you ignore it but I hereby submit it for your consideration:

If you know your users are going to need something then of course don't lazy-load it unless you're worried about initial time-to-interaction metrics. Otherwise, if you are loading more than the user will probably need then you probably aren't using modules aggressively enough.

Also my judgy stance is that a "shared" folder makes sense as a way of organizing things but `src/app/shared/shared.module.ts` is a malignant tumor that will hurt your development speed, unit testing, quality, and performance. By the time anyone realizes the monster they've built, it's too large to tame.